How to get square root with decimal value of large integer?
My code for large integer sqrt
<?php

$y2 = gmp_init('28626386478758000000000000909090904'); // Example GMP number
$sqrt = gmp_sqrt($y2);
echo "Square root is: " . gmp_strval($sqrt) . "\n"; // Output the square root

?>

It gives result
Square root is: 169193340527214604

But how to get decimal part of sqrt?

This might be of help.
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1277652/calculate-fractional-part-of-square-root-without-taking-square-root

For large integer input

To compute the square root of an arbitrarily large number, you can use the bcsqrt() function of the BCMath extension:
echo bcsqrt('28626386478758000000000000909090904', 20);

Output:
169193340527214604.67074165428427766793


This solution is correct: demo
